# Mono-Server issues with DLL's not updating

Tags: c#, mono

*Edited per issue
For some reason mono is not detecting when I have made changes to pretty much anything other than the aspx markup, I have written some code, Found a bug, Killed the bug, uploaded the new files and the bug is still present, In fact if I change another file (I purposly buggered up a CSV file to make it error) It reads it as if it was still the old file (Even after checking and saving it on the server) It is almoste like a Cache issue, But I have reset, reloaded apache. as well as my browser, tested from other machines etc. And that solves nothing, Anyone who could help with this would be brilliant.

Thank you for reading.